# How to extend the eclipse bottom border

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Which extension point can I use in order to extend the bottom part of the eclipse interface?
I am referring to the part as seen above:
[image]

I am interested in the `File Search...` section.

Comment: What do you mean by 'extend'? That part of the status line belongs to the search manager. If you want to run a search read the 'Search support' section of the Programmer's Guide in the Platform Plug-in Developer Guide in the help.

Comment: @greg-449 I want to add a different color to the text, rearrange where the `File Search...` part is shown( I want to move it on left) and also to add some plugin specific messages there.

Comment: Colors you might be able to do by CSS. For the rest you would have to investigate the org.eclipse.search plugin's source.